# How to follow reference between tabs in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Google sheets has a shortcut to follow a reference in other tab?

I searched in excel and it looks like it's F5, but I don't have excel to try it out, and F5 in the web reloads the page, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that Google Sheets has that feature, hence no shortcut either.

See the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page.